# Strange video non/detection by monitors

Tags: linux, display, vga

I have an Atom-based mini PC used as a Linux server that I usually don't connect a display to. When I do, it's an old CRT monitor via VGA. The console shows up just fine, and eventually I can log on on the console. (I don't run any X11 or such on it, just terminal)

However, when I instead connect a more modern flat panel via its VGA port:

1. Grub displays just fine
2. The part of the boot output that (I think) is the initial ramdisk displays just fine
3. Then the display goes dark. I tried all sorts of things but I cannot see anything on the display from this point.

To make things even stranger: if I boot with the CRT display connected, and after the boot is complete, I unplug the CRT and connect the flat panel, stuff gets displayed on the flat panel!

What's going on here? How can I use my flat planel without the CRT's help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works if I add

```
video=LVDS-1:d
```

to the kernel boot arguments.